# my unit test fails due to Bitmap can not be created

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I can not test this **getGeneratedBitmap** function, since Bitmap can not be created.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap

class BitmapGenerator(query: String, private val width: Int, private val height: Int) {

    private var sizeExpansion: SizeExpansion = SizeExpansion(query, width, height)

    private var bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    private var expandedQuery: String

    private var colors: IntArray

    private var colorsLength: Int = 0

    init {
        colorsLength = sizeExpansion.getExpectedLength()
        expandedQuery = sizeExpansion.getExpandedString()
        colors = IntArray(colorsLength)
        generateColorArray()
    }

    private fun generateColorArray(): IntArray {
        for (x in 0 until colorsLength) {
            colors[x] = ColorGenerator().generateColorAccToChar(expandedQuery[x])
        }
        return colors
    }

    fun getGeneratedBitmap(): Bitmap {
        bitmap.setPixels(colors, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)
        return bitmap
    }
}
```

The way I trying to test is:

```
import org.junit.Test

import org.junit.Assert.*

class BitmapGeneratorTest {

@Test
fun getGeneratedBitmap() {
    assertNotEquals(BitmapGenerator("salih",25,25).getGeneratedBitmap(),null)
}
}
```

When I run this test, it throws exception on `Bitmap.createBitmap`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bitmap.createBitmap(widt… Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) must not be null
```

Comment: And what was the exception thrown?  DOn't say it threw an exception without posting the full stack trace.

Comment: JVM unit test or androidTest?

Comment: it is  at (/src/test/java/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it is at (/src/test/java/)

These are JVM unit tests that run without any Android runtime. Usually JVM unit tests are configured in a way where Android platform methods return default values. A `null` is a default value for a method returning a reference type, such as `Bitmap.createBitmap()`. Trying to assign this null to a Kotlin nonnull type causes the runtime exception.

Two common approaches:

- Refactor your code in a way that the surface area to Android SDK methods is minimized so you can test most of your code with plain JVM unit tests. Various MV* architectural patterns help there.
- Run your tests with Android dependencies on an Android runtime, i.e. make it an androidTest.

Answer (score 0):

an `IllegalStateException` is something very else than a failed assertation.

these line looks strange to me, because the arguments (probably) were not previously assigned:

```
private var sizeExpansion: SizeExpansion = SizeExpansion(query, width, height)
private var bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
```

I can see the `private val width: Int, private val height: Int` ...but still wonder about it.

first define `var bitmap: Bitmap` and assign the value on `init {}` (as the name might hint for).

... and move the test to `src/androidTest`.