# How to do unit test for Bitmap in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, bitmap

I want to write unit test for my DiskLruCache class which actually check the bitmap is writing properly in cache and we can verify that by getting the bitmap. I am using below code for bitmap creation in test class but its showing error.

```
var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
```

Its showing `IllegalStateException bitmap can not be null`

Then change the code to:

```
var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
```

And it's showing `NullPointerException`

Any idea how to create bitmap in test class for unit testing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [my unit test fails due to Bitmap can not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239227/my-unit-test-fails-due-to-bitmap-can-not-be-created)

Comment: Where do you put your test file? `/src/test/java/`? If that's the case then the test is executed without any Android runtime meaning that all Android dependencies that are used will return their default values (which is pretty volatile for a test). You need to put your tests in `src/test/androidTest`, have a look at the test documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/test#test_types_and_location

Comment: Its in src/test/kotlin/ directory. Is it possible to do this by keeping in this directory?

Comment: No, you have to switch to `src/androidTest/kotlin` and make it an instrumented test, here's an example: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check this during unit tests because your environment is not real. In unit testing you test Presenter/ViewModel (which have not to contain any android logic).

If you want to check this behaviour you should write Espresso test, do action after which image should be stored in cache and check your cache.